# Projective transformations no longer available in TensorFlow 2.0 what can I do?

Tags: python, tensorflow, computer-vision

My team are switching to TensorFlow 2.0. I'm working on a data augmentation pipeline. TensorFlow 1.X had `tf.contrib.image.transform` that allows for projective transformations. TensorFlow doesn't have the transform function in `tf.image` and it certainly doesn't have a `tf.contrib` module.

I considered other options for data augmentation:

- NVIDIA DALI allows only for affine transformations with 6 parameters.
- Python package Augmentor supports projective transformations but it operates on PIL images and not tensors.

Answer (score 3):

Functionality previous included in `tf.contrib.image.transform` is in the process of being upgraded to `TF 2.0` and migrated to TensorFlow Addons ([`tfa.image`](https://github.com/tensorflow/addons/tree/master/tensorflow_addons/image)). If you have an immediate need for a specific endpoint that has not yet been added, please file it as an issue in the Addons repo.

Migration, deprecation, and rename fates for `tf.contrib` endpoints are detailed in the TensorFlow organization RFC [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/community/blob/master/rfcs/20180907-contrib-sunset.md).