# Affine Transform in TensorFlow 2.0

Tags: affinetransform, tensorflow2.0

How to code Affine Transform in TensorFlow 2.0 that can work for digital images?

I've tried tf.keras.preprocessing.image.apply_affine_transform from TensorFlow 1.14 but TensorFlow 2.0 has no such transform. Now I need it for TensorFlow 2.0.

Comment: This answer can be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55752196/9055614

Comment: You have in tensorflow addons: https://www.tensorflow.org/addons/api_docs/python/tfa/image/transform_ops

Comment: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image/apply_affine_transform

Answer (score 0):

The comment of @lanery leads me to the answer provided by tensorflow [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image/apply_affine_transform)
This was not avaiable in  1.4 < tensorflow <= 2.3